# Babel is unable to parse double colon despite there being a babel config present

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-jest

[image]

I am trying to run build on a directory using Babel. I have a babel.config.js set up in the same directory. I would have expected this to compile but my lack of understanding of how Javascript runs is not letting me proceed here. Could someone please point out what could be going wrong?

Comment: What do the colons mean there? Does it mean something special in Jest or something? I've never seen that sort of thing before

Comment: I believe what you intended is to get a method reference; javascript is not java, you can drop the double colon.

Comment: Google tells me it is the javascript bind operator. I, however, like many before me, do not understand the significance of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-function-bind) say that to use it, you need to:

(1) Install the plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind
```

(2) Add it to your Babel config:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind"]
}
```

Or, you could go back to the old syntax without using Babel at all:

```
this.on('client:beforeCommand', (...args) => this.onBeforeCommand(...args));
```